# Rails 4 link to static file in public in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, public

In a Rails 4 app, I have a static file stored in the `/public` directory.  And I have a view partial that links to that file like this:

```
<%= "Please download the #{link_to 'Static file', '/static_filename.docx'}".html_safe %>
```

The partial is used in both a regular view and in a mailer view.  In the regular view, this works perfectly, and the link url is like this:

```
www.example.com/static_filename.docx
```

But in the mailer, the url comes out like this, missing the host name:

```
/static_filename.docx
```

This, despite the fact that I took care to configure the default url in `config/environments/production.rb` as such:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://www.example.com' }
```

I'm puzzled as to what I am doing wrong, and why the regular view works when the mailer does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should your asset host for action mailer

```
 config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://www.yourdomain.com"
```

Secondly, use the asset_path() wrapper on your asset, ie

```
 <%= "Please download the #{link_to 'Static file', asset_path('/static_filename.docx')}".html_safe %>
```